# TypeError: Member "initialize" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract PartyRegistry

Tags: delegatecall

I'm calling a contract like so:

```
PartyRegistry(partyClone).initialize(
            msg.sender,
            partyInfo,
            stableCoin,
            initialDeposit,
            PLATFORM_ADDRESS
        );
```

And the contract that I'm calling doesn't have an initialize function explicitly defined but instead has a fallback function that does a delegatecall to a contract that does have the initialize function:

```
fallback () payable external {
        address target = logic_contract;
        console.log("before delegate call");
    assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
        calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize())
        let result := delegatecall(gas(), target, ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
        let size := returndatasize()
        returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)
        switch result
        case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
        case 1 { return(ptr, size) }
    }
        console.log("after delegate call");
    }
```

However I'm unable to call initialize and am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Member "initialize" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract PartyRegistry.
  --> contracts/legacy/PartyFactory.sol:99:9:
   |
99 |         PartyRegistry(partyClone).initialize(
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

How do I make sure that initialize is called and goes to the fallback function that ultimately calls initialize with delegatecall?

PartyRegistry is:

```
contract PartyRegistry is PartyStorage, Ownable {
    address public logic_contract;
    
    function setLogicContract(address _c) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        logic_contract = _c;
    return true;
    }

    fallback () payable external {
        address target = logic_contract;
        console.log("before delegate call");
    assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
        calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize())
        let result := delegatecall(gas(), target, ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
        let size := returndatasize()
        returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)
        switch result
        case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
        case 1 { return(ptr, size) }
    }
        console.log("after delegate call");
    }

    receive () payable external {}

}
```

The function initialize looks like this:

```
      function initialize(
        address creator,
        partyinfo memory _partyinfo,
        address dasset,
        uint256 initialdeposit,
        address platform
    ) external payable initializer {...}
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of `PartyRegistry` ?

Comment: updated with PartyRegistry

Comment: Can you share the function definition of the `initialize` function too? Will need its parameters to use it here.

Comment: Updated with initialize

Answer (score 1):

To interact with the PartyRegistry contract via its fallback function, we'll need to create an interface with the `initialize` function.

```js
interface IAnotherContract {
    function initialize(
        address creator,
        partyinfo memory _partyinfo,
        address dasset,
        uint256 initialdeposit,
        address platform
    ) external payable;
}
```

Now to call PartyRegistry, call `initialize` function using the `IAnotherContract` interface instead of `PartyContract` interface.

```js
IAnotherContract(partyClone).initialize(
    msg.sender,
    partyInfo,
    stableCoin,
    initialDeposit,
    PLATFORM_ADDRESS
);
```

What's happening here is by using the right interface, we tell solidity how to encode the function parameters properly while making the call to `PartyRegistry` contract.